# slow jquery treeview loading

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, treeview

I have a jquery treeview which I grabbed from http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

when the number of nodes and sub nodes were small I had no problem loading the tree, but as the content grows the loading is taking very long time almost to the point that using the treeview seems a bad idea.

this is part of my view where I construct the treeview

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("#Ul1").treeview({

            collapsed: true,
            prerendered: true

        });


    });

</script>
```

```
<ul id="Ul1" class="treeview-black">
<%
    foreach (var t in (IEnumerable<itemSpecifications>)ViewData["items"])
{%>

    <li class="expandable"><span><%=Html.RouteLink(t.itemName, null, new { controller = "RQA", action = "itemaction", policyname = t.itemName})%></span>
     <%if (t.itemCount > 0)
       {%>

                <%for(int i=0;i<t.itemCount ;i++){%>
                                                     <ul>
                                                                <li class="expandable"><span><%=Html.RouteLink(t.subitems[i].Name, null, new { controller = "controller1", action = "itemUpdate", rule = t.subitems[i] })%></span></li>


                                                  </ul> 
                                                <%}%>


      <%}%>

<% }%>
</li>

</ul>
```

and the controller contains the code below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {     

            items1 = (from itemsInfo itemInfo in _itemInfoCollection
                         where itemInfo.Name == "val1"  
                         select new itemSpecifications
                         {
                             itemName = itemInfo.Name,
                          itemCount = GetItemscount(),                                 subitems = GetSubItems()                             });

              ViewData["items"] = items1 ;
               return View();
    }
```

sometimes the loading of the entire page takes so long that the page basicaly crashes (unable to load) and sometimes when the page loads successfully and I click on any of the plus signs next to the nodes it takes such a long time to open the subitems. it is worth to mention that the average subnodes are 400 items, any advise will be highly appreciated, I am using MVC3 and it is in IE

Thanks

Comment: Wow any chance you would happen to know how many total nodes are on the page (parents + children + children's children, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds / looks like the page in question is loading the entire structure on initial load. That is what the "prerendered" flag does. Because your list is so large (x Nodes + 400 items per Node), you are looking at significant client-side performance issues, especially in older IE browsers, which performs very badly with JS operations.

It *might* be better if you load each sub menu dynamically rather than pre-rendering it. The only issue is that as the DOM grows, it will eventually get slower.

Could you provide a sample of the depth of objects you are attempting to render, as well as the number of parameters of each? Don't need REAL data, just counts. I.e. Node level 1 has 5 params and there can be as many as 500 nodes on level 1; Node level 2 has 12 params and there can be 400 nodes on level 2, etc.

Comment: there are 27 original nodes/classes(each node is the name of the class and there are other members of the class that are themselves list of other classes) on average those 27 nodes have between 250 to 450 nodes some have much less of course. and the original 27 nodes have only one layer of sub nodes so there is no other layer in depth. to understand your suggestion correctly I have a question though, I read about loading each node upon click but I did not find an example code that does that, so to create a related ajax function that can take the node name and return the class of that node

Comment: So that could be anywhere from 500 to 10,000+. 500 is actually a pretty big number in this case - it sounds like the TreeView is binding one or more functions to each node. Curious how well this performs in another browser - Chrome for example?

Comment: For AJAX, you'll have to expose the nodes as JSON on a separate server call, and then be able to pass parameters to it upon click of the tree so it will grab that set of nodes and render them.

Comment: have not tested yet, but can you advise any samples for dynamic load? so when a user clicks on a node the tree loads the sub nodes

Comment: @Sue, http://www.jstree.com/ supports AJAX loading. Have a look at that and its documentation.

Comment: Dear Josh, I have been checking the link and it is really good, but I was thinking to ask you if you have any examples that explicitly assign a viewdata to the jstree, I can open up the jstree but my project pulls out several nodes and then subnodes all included in a viewdata, I will really appreciate any help!

Comment: @Josh let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2542/discussion-between-sue-and-josh)